# Site filter does not include Meta

Tags: bug, meta, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

[Stack Exchange filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) allows one to subscribe to all questions from selected sites, including per-site metas. Conspicuously absent from the list of sites under "Just these sites" is *this* Meta. I do not see it on the list, whether or not the box "show meta sites" is checked.

Comment: Stack Apps is also missing.

Comment: However, if you search for a tag across all sites, such as with the [`all-featured` filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/384940/all-featured), it does include Meta SE (and, interestingly, also include [tag:destaque], [tag:важное], [tag:注目], and other internationalised equivalent tags).